# How do I make a static GeoDataManagerConfiguration in my Lambda function handler?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, configuration, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I've been told that if a lambda function acting on a DynamoDB table uses DynamoDB's spatial indexing and has a lot of queries run at once, one needs to make their instance of GeoDataManagerConfiguration static.

This apparently stops a threadpool from being created for each invocation which can lead to a memory error like so:

```
"errorMessage":"unable to create new native thread","errorType":"java.lang.OutOfMemoryError"
```

when attempting to do a spatial query via DynamoDB's spatial library.

As of now I am invoking my GeoDataManagerConfiguration like so:

```
GeoDataManagerConfiguration config = new GeoDataManagerConfiguration(ddb, "geo");
```

How do I make this static and avoid the creation of thread pools for each invocation/request?

Thanks